# Mouse-over, hover on Wordpress site not showing sub navigation

Tags: html, css, wordpress, genesis

I have set up a site using a Wordpress site Genesis framework. The problem is that if I hover over certain main navigation links, the sub nav does not display.

If you go to the home page and go over the "about" main navigation link, for instance, the sub navigation does not show. It's only when you actually click on the work "about" does the sub navigation take you to another page and show the sub navigation links.

I have looked at Lynda.com tutorials, asked Studiopress (although they direct me to another third -party site that is super unhelpful) amongst various sites, but have not found something to help.

Any ideas?

The site is: http://lolabernabe.com/wordpress/

Many thanks in advance.
Lola

[link to diagram/jpeg with comments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4W8Lu.jpg)

Comment: I have noticed that you didn't add any submenu item. Add a submenu item

Comment: Hi Dev.Please explain.If you click on "about" on the home page, you will see the sub menu items.

Comment: Dev Kiran is Right. First you add sub menu item under the "about".

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I did add it, if you click on "about" it will show you the submenu "board, community partners, staff..." etc. Sorry if I am unclear. But I don't understand. Do you mean in the CSS something is missing?

Comment: Just in case this is what my primary menu looks like in Wordpress with the sub-navigation items: http://tinypic.com/r/28apc0y/9